# Explore mode GeoIP data not available

Tags: xdb, experience-editor, configuration, mvc, tracking

In Sitecore Experience Editor Explore view I am facing one issue in which I am not getting any country list in GeoIP section under Visitor information. Below is the screenshot of my page.
[image]

Please suggest if there is any configuration setting or any other setting which I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it happens when Tracker.Current.Interaction is null:

```
public GeoIpViewerData GetViewerData()
{
    CurrentInteraction interaction = Tracker.Current.Interaction;
    if (interaction == null)
        return GeoIpViewerData.Empty;
    GeoIpData geoIpData = this.GetGeoIpData(interaction.GeoData, interaction.Ip != null ? new IPAddress(interaction.Ip) : (IPAddress) null);
    GeoIpMode mode = this.ResolveGeoIpMode(geoIpData);
    MapProviderData mapProvider = this._geoIpHelper.GetMapProvider();
    return new GeoIpViewerData(geoIpData, mode, mapProvider);
}
```